# Cannot set up my ASP.NET 3.5 website on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

I've created several IIS websites in my life, but some days ago a friend of mine asked me to host his website, so I created a folder within inetpub/wwwroot to store it.

Then, I created a virtual directory in my Default Web Site(the folder appears there as it's on wwwroot) and created the application, and allowed scripts & executables permissions. Also, I've set up the proper document types the website will have(default.aspx, asp, etc) and the folder has all the permissions i usually grant: iusr, iwmp, asp.net, network, etc.

When I reset IIS services and then look at the website(I've added the headers too) I get the following error:

> You have attempted to execute a CGI,
>   ISAPI, or other executable program
>   from a directory that does not allow
>   programs to be executed.

I've been searching for a while on internet and the only thing I found is to allow Executables to my website, which I've already done.

But, when I deleted the asp.net pages and I only add an html file, it will display on the browser.

Does anyone have any clue about this?

Comment: What version of IIS are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Go into Web Server Extensions folder under IIS manager and make sure you have allowed asp.net 2.0 apps to run

Comment: Its allowed. This website is running under 3.5 framework though. Do I have to add it to the web server extensions too? In that case, which dll file do I have to add?

Answer (score 1):

Your IUSR account needs read/write permissions on the directory you created.

Comment: @Matt - If the wrong NTFS permissions were set for the anonymous user account you'd get a popup in the browser asking for credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting definitely means that your script *Execute Permissions* are incorrect. In IIS Manager, go back to the folder in question and double check the setting on the Directory tab of the folder/virtual directory in question.

You should also try this with a classic ASP script (with just `<% Response.Write "Hello" %>` in the file) just to make sure, but I'm sure the result will be the same.

If you're still having problems, open the IIS metabase (in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\metabase.xml`) and locate the folder in question. To do this, search for (assuming that you put the site under the Default Web Site) the following string:

> `Location ="/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT"`

This should locate the `IIsWebVirtualDir` for the root of the Default Web Site. It'll look like this:

```
<IIsWebVirtualDir Location ="/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT"`
  AccessFlags="AccessRead | AccessScript"
  AppFriendlyName="Default Application"
     ...other attributes...
  >
</IIsWebVirtualDir>
```

Scroll down a bit until you find a location path that matches the folder you put your friends website into e.g.

> `Location ="/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/JoesSite"`

When you've found this, take a look at the `AccessFlags` attribute, it should look like:

> `AccessFlags="AccessRead | AccessScript"`

Tell us what you see on that metabase node.

Answer (score -1):

Well, as it's a website and not a web application, it seems that it didn't work as a virtual directory, but it did as a IIS website.

Thank you.

Brian

Answer (score -1):

open iis. then select application pool in the left pane .select the specified site in the pool.right click and open advanced setting and then change the .NET version as required